# Can you send push message only for selected users?

Tags: iphone, apns

I'm an absolute newbie in Apple development, and I just want to know something special:

Is it possible to send a push message not for all downloaders of the app, but some selected users?

I thought about two possibilities

- send apple the push message command just for some selected devices
- decide in the app wether to show the push or not

If this is not possible at all, I do not have to keep on developing.

Comment: I was a bit quick to vote to close this, since it's not a question about code, it *can* be on topic for this site.

Comment: Should I post it on stack overflow?

Comment: It should be OK for this community. If you want a definitive answer, wait for a mod, but in any case try not to double-post across sites, if it belongs on SO or programmers, someone here will migrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an exact "developer" answer, but from the usage of app like Facebook or Twitter, it is definitively possible to send a push notification to selected user.

Since the main goal of push notification is saving battery, I'd say deciding in the app if a notification is shown or not is not the smartest way, since you'll have to send the data to the phone.

I would say that (and that's where I don't have hard facts) Apple keeps an unique ID for every iPhone that you can use on your server as well so that you'll only have to send to Apple to **which** phone you want to send the notification to.